# Does a heavy drop-in fireclay kitchen sink need mounting clips for installation?

Tags: kitchen-sink

The sink I bought didn't come with mounting clips. It weighs 75 pounds. Is 100% silicone on the drop in lip enough to secure it in place?

Comment: Just be really careful with the "drop-in" process - don't smash fingers!

Answer (score 2):

**YES** Silicone caulk is actually a very strong adhesive once cured. In fact, I would say you will not be able to move the sink even if you deliberately try to. Also, there will be no significant lateral forces during normal use; the weight of the sink + the silicone will be fine.

Comment: Some drop ins don’t have brackets for clips, the silicone and plumbing usually are enough for those.